# How do i remove databases with Realm?

Tags: swift, realm

I'd like to delete databases of realm.
I know how to delete that on Java, but I need to do that on swift

like this(Java):

```
RealmConfiguration realmConfig = new RealmConfiguration.Builder(this).build();
Realm.deleteRealm(realmConfig);
realm = Realm.getInstance(realmConfig);
```

thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to delete Realm's files

```
let manager = NSFileManager.defaultManager()
let realmPath = Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration.path as! NSString
let realmPaths = [
  realmPath as String,
  realmPath.stringByAppendingPathExtension("lock")!,
  realmPath.stringByAppendingPathExtension("log_a")!,
  realmPath.stringByAppendingPathExtension("log_b")!,
  realmPath.stringByAppendingPathExtension("note")!
]
for path in realmPaths {
  do {
    try manager.removeItemAtPath(path)
  } catch {
    // handle error
  }
}
```

From Realm's official documentation: 
https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#deleting-realm-files

Answer (score 0):

Best thing to do is to call `deleteAll()` method on realm object like:

```
let realm = try! Realm()

try! realm.write {
  realm.deleteAll()
}
```